# PHP - adding a string to a variable (array) CSV --> MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli, csvtoarray

I have a problem thats just baffling my mind, I'm unable to add a string gradually loaded from a CSV file to an array (through a while loop) which after writes to a database.

The code runs, it echoes the fact that it has written to the database, but nothing actually happens, when I remove the string it writes to the database just fine.

The syntax should be 
$variable = 'string' . $csvValue;
It won't write to the database when this is the case, but it will when it is:
$variable = $csvValue;

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Script to insert data from a CSV-file with AD information in it to a MySQL database.

// Connect to the database 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","dbname"); 

if(!$connect){
   die('Could not <span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">
    connect to</span> MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Charset
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

// File path
define('CSV_PATH','/home/administrator/Desktop/'); 

$csvName = CSV_PATH . "AnsattInfo.csv"; // Name of CSV-file
$csvfile = fopen($csvName, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;

while(!feof($csvfile)){

    $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 2048);
    $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
    $insert_csv = array();
    $insert_csv['sAMAccountName'] = $csv_array[0];
    $insert_csv['displayName'] = $csv_array[1];
    $insert_csv['employeeNumber'] = $csv_array[2];
    $insert_csv['mail'] = $csv_array[3];
    $insert_csv['company'] = $csv_array[4];
    $footer = str_replace(' ', '_', $insert_csv['company']);
    //$footer = '@' . str_replace(' ', '_', $insert_csv['company']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO playsms_tblUserTest (status, username, enable_webservices, webservices_ip, name, mobile, email, footer, country, datetime_timezone, language_module, fwd_to_mobile, send_as_unicode)
        VALUES(
            3,
            ".$insert_csv['sAMAccountName'].",
            1,
            '*.*.*.*',
            ".$insert_csv['displayName'].",
            ".$insert_csv['employeeNumber'].",
            ".$insert_csv['mail'].",
            ".$footer.",
            137,
            '+0100',
            'nb_NO',
            1,
            1         
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE name = $insert_csv[displayName], mobile = $insert_csv[employeeNumber], email = $insert_csv[mail], footer = $footer";

   mysqli_query($connect, $query);

   $i++;
}

fclose($csvfile);

echo "CSV successfully imported to User-table! \n";

mysqli_close($connect); // closing connection  
?>
```

What I actually want to do here is to add a string infront of the $footer value, as @ is groupname of a contact group, where '@' is actually the indicator of it being a group.

In the CSV file the company name does not have a '@' infront of it, which is what I want to add. Like this:

```
$footer = '@' . str_replace(' ', '_', $insert_csv['company']);
```

This does not give any syntax errors, but nothing actually gets written to the database.

Does anyone have a suggestion on a solution here?

Cheers for any help.

Comment: that may be stupid of me, have you tried to comment the other line that manage footer while using @ dot replace? have you tried to debug a little to echo as example the $footer or the $query? what you see?

Comment: When I echo on the @ version of the footer I get echoes like this: 
@"<company name>"
@"<company name>"
@"<company name>"
@
@
@@@
@"<company name>"
@

So I guess It might have something to do with the users that doesnt have a company name attached to them that might be the problem?

Comment: well, i don't know why it does work for you without the concatenation, but strings still should be in quotes in mysql-queries. my second guess is, that php/mysqli automatically does the quotes for you if a string is recognized - but it won't recognize `@value` as a string, because words that start with `@` are considered variables (mysql-variables) in mysql.

Comment: I've tried with a random string as well thinking of that low_rents, I for example tried $footer = 'asd' . str_replace(' ', '_', $insert_csv['company']);

Comment: @robikar can you echo the `$query` variable and post what your mysql-string finally looks like?

Comment: Ok, I got some progress:
I did this: $footer = '"@"' . str_replace(' ', '_', $insert_csv['company']);

Which now writes to the database, but with quotes like "@""<company name>".

I tried to solve this by changing the $footer to $atSign, and changed the $footer to then replace all quotation marks with nothing, which worked in the echo looking like @<company name>, but with this "fix" it once again wouldnt write to the database.

Comment: When echoing the query with the "'@'" . $variable it all looks correct with the "@""<company name" being the only mistake. 

When echoing the query with '@' . $variable it shows only the static values inserted, and none of the actual dynamic ones from the csv file. the $footer part of the query is not entirely empty, as it shows the static @, but not the actual company name.

Comment: @robikar and what if you are adding the single-quotes in the php-concatenation-part like this: `$footer = "'@" . str_replace(' ', '_', $insert_csv['company']) . "'";` ?

Comment: Same error as before (doesnt show any of the dynamic values), only difference is that the @ is now in single quotes '@'. No writing to the database.

Comment: I found a dirty way to fix it. I've done with thing I described earlier with the '"@'" . str_replace(' ', '_', $insert_csv['company']);

Which then writes to the database with the quotation marks, I then on the update run a variable named @footerUpdate which does a str_replace('"','', $footer); 

This obviously is not a good way to do it, if I try to do the str_replace of the quotes in the insert itself, I get the same problem as before.

Comment: @robikar i am currently at work. but maybe i can took a closer look at it at home. i really wonder why this turns out to be so complicated.

Comment: I just figured out the problem, it seems like the problem all along was the quotations on the $footer in the UPDATE statement. Which made no sense to me as I had the problem before I wrote the UPDATE statement, I guess at that point I had another error that stopped me from getting it to work.

Answer (score 2):

if the field `footer` in your database is of some "string-type", then you also have to fill it with a string:

```
/* ... */
            ".$insert_csv['employeeNumber'].",
            ".$insert_csv['mail'].",
            '".$footer."',
            137,
            '+0100',
            'nb_NO',
            1,
            1         
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE name = $insert_csv[displayName], mobile = $insert_csv[employeeNumber], email = $insert_csv[mail], footer = '$footer'";
/* ... */
```

and to declare it as a string in your mysql-query you have to put it in between quotes like shown above with the `$footer` value.

i think you got the same error multiple times in your query:
for example `$insert_csv['mail']` will be a string too, i guess.

**hint:** if you used some kind of error-handling, then you would have seen that there is some mysql-error (since i am using `pdo` i don't really know how this works in `mysqli`).

Comment: When trying to add quotes to for example I get a syntax error in terminal that says theres unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING), or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in <filepath>.

Comment: @robikar well, then you got some parse-error in the query-string. but that doesn't mean, that it wouldn't work when you get rid of those parse errors :)

Comment: You happen to see any of those? I've linked the entire script, only thing I edited out was the db connection info along with the $password variable, which currently only copies the username as password, as this service is still in the testing phase I'm not worrying about fetching passwords somehow from the AD. If you have any clue of how to "decrypt" the password up towards AD to check if the password is correct. (The service Im working on is on ubuntu, while the AD server is obviously Windows based)  I'd appreciate the help, but thats not a prio now.